# Comparing 3 arrays of various NSObject Subclasses

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, compare, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary which contains 3 NSArrays,

```
- posts
- comments
- likes.
```

And in each array are consistent NSObject Subclasses:

```
- Post
- Comment
- Like
```

Usually, I would just put all objects from these three arrays into one array and compare them using the same variable which they all contain, but in this case, `Posts` has the variable `dateOfUpload` and `Like` and `Comment` have the same variable, date.

How can I compare the objects from these three arrays using the variable `date` and `dateOfUpload` to create one big array of all objects in descending date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to add all your objects in one big array and sort using a block as follows:

```
// Create the array with all the objects
NSMutableArray *stuff = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:posts.allValues];
[stuff addObjectsFromArray:comments.allValues];
[stuff addObjectsFromArray:likes.allValues];

// Sort it by using a block
NSArray *sortedStuff = [stuff sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [obj1 respondsToSelector:@selector(date)]? [obj1 date] : [obj1 dateOfUpload];
    NSDate *date2 = [obj2 respondsToSelector:@selector(date)]? [obj2 date] : [obj2 dateOfUpload];
    return [date2 compare:date1]; // Objects are reversed to get descending order
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make them all implement method like:

```
-(NSComparsionResult) compareByDate : (NSObject *) obj;
```

Of course you'll need to implement this in different way in each class.
Then make one big array from all the tree arrays and call

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareByDate:)];
```